# Fetch last request in PDO multi query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How to fetch the result last query in case of a PDO multi query?

Here is the sample code

```
$sql = <<<OEF
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...;

    SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...
OEF;

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    //not work
}
```

`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` is set to true in order to execute many queries at a time.

Comment: Why do you think you need a multi query here?

Comment: @YourCommonSense It's just a matter of project organization. There's a dev team who does only SQL, gather as many SQL as possible in a file; the other does PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

Just run your queries in separate calls. It will be much more clean and robust solution

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...");
$stmt->execute($params1);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...");
$stmt->execute($params2);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    // everything is all right
}
```

Comment: I would do that if there's really 0 solution to my need. If you think it's not possible, I would also accept it as an answer then move on. I've also tried the seperation, if the first sql has many queries, calling for `while ($stmt->nextRowset()) {}` or `$stmt->closeCursor()` is necessary. Only the former has error detection.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the first sql has many queries". the poit is to run every query separately. That aside, given you are already aware of the nextRowset, I don't understand what your problem is - why don't you just use it right away